# Who is considered the most powerful species in the Star Trek Universe?

Tags: star-trek

Who is considered to be the most powerful species in the Star Trek Universe? We know the Borg are powerful but they can be beaten by species 8472, but species 8472 can be beaten by the Federation (Not really a species more of a group of species) and then the Federation can be beaten by the Borg, it is a vicious circle but what about other species in the galaxy could any of them be more powerful? Some people might say 'Q' but is 'Q' really a species or a mystical force?

I was going to edit this question to exclude 'Q' from it, but there are some species that even 'Q' is scared of for example Guinan's species. In the episode 'Q Who' 'Q' tells Picard that she is a danger to the crew, but 'Q' is scared and becomes agitated by Guinans presence. This is backed up by wiki under plot

> Guinan confronts Q who becomes agitated and is forced to reveal the reason why he is on the Enterprise'

So is 'Q' really the most powerful species or is Guinan's species more powerful?

Comment: I'm **very** tempted to say, "The Great Bird of the Galaxy," since that's the name of the creator of the whole thing, but I guess that's not in-universe.

Comment: @TangoOversway: I see your "Great Bird" and raise by [The Pakled](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Pakled).

Comment: Is it the Ferengi!? ;)

Comment: @Secko The Ferengi do seem to thrive wherever they end up...

Comment: @Izkata Yes, they assimilate money. Hence the Ferengi rules of [acquisition](http://www.vidiot.com/st-ds9/rules.html).

Comment: This whole situation sounds like a big game of [Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_Paper_Scissors_Lizard_Spock) to me.

Comment: Would the Traveler be considered a "Race" or an individual of great power?

Comment: Humans because of their special abilities (Refer: Hide and Q)..

Comment: The [Metrons](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Metron) were also pretty powerful, and haven't been mentioned here yet.

Comment: Just as a side note, my answer would have been Humans too. There is a conversation between Q and Riker, in which Q admits that humans eventually become more powerful and advanced than "his" own race.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

1. Q are a [race of aliens](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/q-aliens).

   > Super-race able to change matter to energy and to suspend time, existing in a continuum of the limitless dimensions of the galaxy.
2. The side effects of [their civil war caused supernovas in our reality](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Q_Continuum).
3. They can convert matter to energy and vice-versa at will.

So, yes. It seems like they are the most powerful.

Comment: Hands down Q. Even the Douwd cannot bring the dead back to life. All of eternity is Q's playground. The Caretaker couldn't even reproduce without finding a compatible mate and died of old age.

Comment: @cp21yos I was to accept your answer, but only because it is the most popular answer, but you have only answered part of the question. Everyone seems to be only answering half the question. Is everyone just ignoring the Guinan theory? I would actually tend to disagree with the theory that 'Q' was the most powerful. Like I add below Power does not always mean Special abilities. That is way I have chosen bitmasks answer as 'The Tau Alpha C'ans' were a very Wise and Intelligent species and that in its self makes them powerful.

Comment: @Popeye "a very Wise and Intelligent species and that in its self makes them powerful." No it doesn't, it makes them wise and intelligent.  Q hands down.

Answer (score 20):

If you want to exclude the Q from your list (otherwise see [cp21yos's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/13766/2565)), there are many more species in the ST Universe that are *a lot* more advanced/powerful than any of the species you listed. Even 8472 seems to be primitive compared to these:

1. [The Douwd](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Douwd)
2. [The Nacene](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Nacene) (aka Caretaker)
3. [The nameless race](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Spaceborne_entity) from TNG 1x01, [Encounter at Farpoint](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Encounter_at_Farpoint_%28episode%29)

But there are probably more which I forgot. At this level it is really hard to say which of these "wins", but I'd bet on the Douwd.

Edit: Possibly even a match for the Q:

- [The Tau Alpha C'ans](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Tau_Alpha_C)

Comment: @drewbenn: Didn't watch ENT, and don't remember TOS too much, sorry.

Comment: +1 for Douwd. Who was the alien with the cat-like face that was pretty powerful?

Comment: @elchief: I think they introduced one for ST:Online, which appeared in no other series, but I never played the game.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to head out into the novels (not official canon), it would have to be [Them](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Them):

> "Them" referred to a race of unnameable beings, greater than any other
>   in existence, including the Q Continuum. "They" were responsible for
>   the creation of the universe, and for the destruction of several
>   previous universes they found insufficiently interesting or otherwise
>   unworthy.
>
> "They" created an artificial world known to the Federation as Gorsach
>   IX, where visitors had to overcome a number of challenges in order to
>   gain an audience with "Them". In 2380, Jean-Luc Picard (with the
>   assistance of Q), found these beings, and was put in the position of
>   representing the entire universe, and its worthiness to continue.
>   Recognizing the absurdity of his situation, Picard laughed -- a
>   reaction "They" deemed grounds to allow the universe to survive. (TNG
>   novel: Q & A)

Comment: Is this from a movie, TV episode or an extended universe work?

Comment: @HNL I believe this is from the novels, if you follow the link in the answer in reads that Worf is now Picards commander. And I am pretty sure I have read about them in a book.

Comment: @HNL It says in the answer it's from a novel, which is extended universe ;)  Specifically, if you click the link, it's the TNG novel "Q & A".

Comment: Oh I see. I was confused by the title "Q & A".

Comment: “In 2380, Jean-Luc Picard... was put in the position of representing the entire universe”. First the human race, now the entire universe, he must have thought. Give me a break. I’m just a Yorkshire lad!

Answer (score 6):

We all do not agree completely about things in life, but here goes my list of the TEN most powerful beings in the Star Trek universe. I have never read a Star Trek novel before so I know nothing about the beings in them. So here goes my list of the Ten Most powerful beings in the Star Trek Universe.

1) The Q simply for the fact that they and him have been around since the beginning of the universe. Q is so powerful that he can be silly with it. He travels through time like we would wind an old watch.

2) The Douwd ( I think I spelled that right). A being so powerful that with a single thought he destroyed 50 billion beings, their whole civilization with a simple thought. Many of you on here says that he do not have the power to restore his wife back to life but I think the reason is that he just did not want to what was done was done. Besides a being that powerful can go back in time to the point before she was killed and change what happened. Put in spite of how powerful the above two beings and their species are they are not perfect at least not 100% perfect like GOD is.

3) The Organians so powerful that Spock said that they were as far above us as were are above an amoeba. They project their will tens if not hundreds of light years and disarmed the whole Federation and Klingon fleets. Making things TOO HOT TO HANDLE.

4) Trelane or something like that. He was the being from the TOS series The Squire of Gathos in which he moved a whole planet through space to block the path of the Enterprise and it crew. Actually I should say that his or its parents are the most powerful when you consider that Trelane was only a child. A very spoil brat at that but a child never the less. If a child could do that, I mean move planets around like that then think about what his mommy and daddy could do without trying. I once read online somewhere that this Trelane was a member of the Q Com, but I am not sure on that.

5) Sargon from the TOS series. At the time the Enterprise USS1701 ran across him he had been alive for over 1/2 a million years probing the universe with his mind. He did have the power to bring back the dead. He was also able to transport Kirk and company through over 100 miles of solid planet. His race was so powerful that if things had worked out they would have given the Federation technology to build starships with engines the size of walnuts.

6)The builders of the Dyson Sphere. When I watch that episode on TNG I often wonder how such a thing could be done. Data said the sphere had a diameter of 250 million kilometers and that it could contain over 250 million M class planets. When you consider that the sun is so huge that it wold take 1 million earths to fill it up we are taking about this thing is big enough to hold 250 times the volume of the sun. Scotty told LaForge just think about the engineering it would take to just design the thing. Anyone in the movies industry that might be reading this, how about making a movie and calling it the builders of the Dyson Sphere. Just think about how long it would have taken to build that thing. And do you ever wonder where they got the material to build it? When you consider that the average distance between stars is about 5 light years and when you also consider that in order to build this sphere you had to dismantle whole planets and somehow convert the planets material to carbon neutronium. I say convert because neutronium is what is left over after a massive star goes nova and when a star becomes a neutron star the left overs is that that big in volume. About the size of a city and it would take billions of them to make a sphere 250 kilometer across. 
I envision for tens of millennium huge star ships in the remote past plowing through space bring loads of matter to the neutronium conversion area to be converted to the stuff. Funny thing though, they were that brilliant but they didn't know the star they were surrounding would become unstable and they would have to leave.

7) The might Iconian Empire maybe I should have placed them in the number 6 position because they were able to move whole stars. They were going to replace the star in their home system but it went nova and destroyed them all or at least those in that system. You can read about that in the Next Generation series I forgot the episode it was in.

8) Gary Mitchell, the glowing eyed human that was change to a godling when the Enterprise tried to break through the galaxy barrier in TOS episode of "Where no man has gone before."  I just wished that they did not have to kill him off but then and again this is make believe and they could revive him in a future series or movie. Which by the way they already did in Star Trek of Gods and Men. But that was a freaky sort of movie but I liked it anyway. I would like to see someone make a movie in which after that rock fell on him in the TOS that right after the Enterprise left orbit his power regenerated so much that he came back to life and turn that planet into a paradise and say doing Next Generation Time some ship revisit that planet and find ole Gary almost as powerful as the Q. Would be interesting to see such a movie. They could call it, "The Resurrection of Gary Mitchell".

9) I don't recall the name of the episode but I know it was on TNG and he was a being running from his people because they wanted to destroy those going through a process that would be the next step in their evolution. I remember Worf falling from a height and this being went down to him and places his hand on Worf and he was made whole again. And that the ship was infected with some sort of illness and he touched the ship and everyone was made well. Later on towards the end of the show he transported those chasing him unto the Enterprise and after that he turned into pure energy and flew off into space.

10) Kes, Neelix' girlfriend on Voyager. She hurled the ship over 10,000 light years out of Borg space after she went through some form of transformation. Not bad for someone that usually live less than a decade. But they had to get rid of her so that super sexy Borg Seven of Nine could come into the picture. Talking about super hot.

So there you have it my choice of the Ten Most Powerful Beings or races in the Star Trek Universe. Wonder how well I did.

Comment: I believe it was the novel "Q Squared" that made Trelane into a Q.

Comment: The power level of the Douwd is debatable. Kevin claimed to have destroyed the Husnock with a thought, a Q-like level of power. But his observable level of power, while formidable, was distinctly more limited. He couldn't shield his thoughts from Troi without disabling her, he couldn't seem to keep track of where the Enterprise was, and he was generally inept in his attempts to hide from the Enterprise. I think it more consistent with his observed power level to assume that he mentally activated a Husnock-destroying superweapon and didn't feel like revealing the details.

Comment: But if the Douwd do possess the singular power of ultimate destruction, it raises the question, "most powerful in what way?" The Douwd may have supreme destructive power, but Kevin Uxbridge seemed very limited in his power to actually achieve his desires. Compared to the Organians, whose power wasn't observably limited by anything except a desire not to unnecessarily interfere with lesser lifeforms.

Comment: #9 must be "The Traveler", right?

Comment: In "Q Squared" it is said that Trelane is a young Q that was using machines to train his power.  The Q we know and love was his teacher (and sort of Uncle) in the TNG era.  So if we include extended universe (novels) then Trelane can be merged with the Q continuum.

Comment: Also in "Q Squared" it is revealed that Gary Mitchell was empowered by Q.  Q had been attacked, thrown backwards in time, and almost destroyed.  He had just begun to gain consciousness in the TOS era and was hanging out in the barrier.  When the Enterprise entered he saw his chance to escape and did so in Gary.  Gary's will was too strong, and so Q divided himself between the two ESPers so that he could escape when Gary was killed.  So if we're included extended universe, Gary should be removed from the list as he was borrowing the powers of the Q Continuum.

Comment: One last note about "Q Squared": Q told Picard that he knew God and was there when God created humans.  "I told him it was a bad idea", I believe was the quote.  The tone of this comment implies that it may not have been completely serious, and Q may have been outright lying.  However, if we take it at face value then that implies that there was a God of some sort in the ST universe, and the implication is that he was/is more powerful than the Q are.  So on that assumption, if we allow extended universe, the unequivocal answer to the OP is: God.  Though I think that answer is unsatisfying.

Comment: What about tribbles?

Answer (score 4):

No one mentioned the Prophets yet?

Or how about this:
Prophets: good
Pagh Wraiths: evil
Q: Neutral.  Earth was the Q's custom race of milky way humanoids.

Comment: Earth is a race now?

Comment: Did the 'Prophets' exude control over standard universe?

Answer (score 1):

If we discount Q then I would think that the most powerful were 'the Organians' from the episode Errand of Mercy in TOS.

The were capable of crippling both Klingon and Federation empires on whim and compelled them into the Organian Peace Treaty.  The had transcended corporeal form and did not seem to expend any effort in stopping the war.

Answer (score -2):

I believe Power, special abilities, intelligence, time/space etc all go back to the same thought.  Overall "power" in whatever form or combination.  The "Q' are far outmatched by others. THEM and the Douwd would seem to me to be better choices.