# Does Trelane have a body of flesh?

Tags: star-trek, aliens, star-trek-tos

It's revealed at the end of "Squire of Gothos" that Trelane's parents are energy-based, which seems to imply that Trelane's true nature is energy. However, this doesn't mean that his body was mere energy during the episode. He may have appeared to be physical (like the EMH), but was truly energy, or he may have actually been a physical entity of some kind.

Trelane challenged Captain Kirk to a duel, and wasted his turn by firing at the ceiling. He then allowed Kirk to fire nearly point-blank at him, not appearing too concerned for his safety. Maybe this attitude was due to Trelane being energy, or maybe his machine could heal him instantly of any damage, etc.

The episode isn't particularly clear, but maybe there is something in the extended works that gives further detail on Trelane's revealed nature. However, McCoy does state that his tricorder doesn't even identify Trelane as "existing at all, alive or dead," which may give credence to the idea that Trelane is simply masquerading as a physical being, but is really energy.

Answer (score 4):

If you ignore extended works, then your own thought process has exhaustively explored the possibilities for Trelane. If you don't, then, because of Q-Squared, Trelane is a member of the Q Continuum, and I refer you to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108430/can-qs-body-be-damaged).

Additionally, when Q was made human, Data's tricorder read him as human.

> DATA: Sir, he is reading as fully human.
> [s3e13 Deja Q](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/161.htm)

Since McCoy's detects nothing, I think that if allow Trelane to be Q, he doesn't have an actual human body.

Comment: @CodeMed, [according to Memory Alpha](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Q-Squared) that's the entire plot of the book.

Comment: @CodeMed My point is that if we do *not* accept EU sources, then we don't have anything to go on beyond what was already thoroughly analyzed in the original post, and if we *do* then Trelane is Q according to Q Squared, in which case the same things that apply to Qs apply to him, i.e, if when a Q with a human form is scanned, they come up human, than if he had a genuinely human form, his would have as well.